# Is in-class initialization "real" when it appears?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 introduced this:

```
struct MyClass {
  int foo = 0; //*
};
```

Until now I've been using this without thinking about it, but now I'm wondering:

Is this initialization doing/executing any actual initialization at this particular line (`//*` in the code), or is this a mere convenience notation that only does/executes something **later**, when the object is actually constructed?

Comment: How would this line of code know which bytes in memory need initialization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "later" and "at this particular line", but the above is equivalent to the following:

```
struct MyClass {
    MyClass() : foo(0) { }
};
```

So if I understand your question correctly, then the answer is: "Yes, only when the object is actually constructed".

Comment: @7cows: Why did you un-accept this answer? Does it not answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Declarations are not executable code, they do not execute anything. This is merely a convenient notation for inserting initialization of `foo` to zero into every constructor that you define (or into an implicitly defined default constructor, if you do not define any constructors yourself).